# Google Doc: onOpen() doesn't execute in copied document+script

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I have a template document with an associated container-bound script.  The script does not require authentication - it simply creates a custom menu in the Google Docs UI.

The template document is owned by my GAE web app.  Creating a new document via the web app uses the following process:

1. Make a copy of the template in the web app's service account.
2. Update the document's media_body with user-supplied content;
3. Insert permissions to set the user as the document owner;
4. Delete the permissions associated with the web app service account so that the document is private to the user that created it.

This process works as expected EXCEPT for the execution of the onOpen() function in the script.  The script is successfully copied along with the document, and onOpen() can be run manually (using the 'Script Manager'), but it doesn't execute automatically when the document is opened.  Removing step 4 solves the problem, but this makes the document 'less than private'.

Why doesn't onOpen() execute in the copied, private document?

Comment: This is pretty peculiar. You are saying that if a service account is collaborator on a spreadsheet, then `onOpen` does not run? Can you run some additional tests like adding this service account as a collaborator on docs where `onOpen` runs fine?

Comment: No, it's the other way around: `onOpen()` does not run after the service account is REMOVED as a collaborator.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the original onOpen runs with the original owner permissions. When you remove that user from the permissions, it wont be able to use those saved credentials.
either dont remove it, or better yet dont change ownership just share it with the user. That will also give you more control since you will own all the system files created.

Comment: This option doesn't enforce the privacy of the created document.

Comment: You would reserve a system account for that. What you want cant be supported because scripts always run on an authorized account (either by publishing or approving oauth scopes). If you remove the approved account from editors, google is not going to run onOpen on a user that has not approved thst script to run on their account.

Comment: Isn't approval unnecessary for scripts that don't access user data, e.g. a script that adds a custom menu?

Comment: But if you go into the "all my triggers" dialog you will see your onOpen as triggers too. They were instslled by the original owner so they can no longer run when you remove that user. Its weird to have a trigger installed on a spreadsheet which doesnt have access.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), "...if Bob opens the Spreadsheet, then the `onOpen` function runs as Bob, irrespective of who added the script to the Spreadsheet."