# Copying a template Docs file's bound script when filling in the template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

My question is similar to this one:
[Google Doc: onOpen() doesn't execute in copied document+script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284139/google-doc-onopen-doesnt-execute-in-copied-documentscript)

I have a Google Docs template owned by Google (generated from a 3rd-party database application). I have a bound script that creates a custom menu to email the resulting product document (plus other PDF attachments based on the email address in the report). The beta script works well with a test doc. However, when the script is copied to the template doc (which is in a shared drive) and I use the 3rd-party product to generate a report, the script is not copied from the template to the report. Interestingly, if I use the `File > Make a copy` menu from the template doc, the script is copied across.

I'm thinking this is a permissions issue when the app interacts with the template but I have no idea how to resolve this.

Any advice is very welcomed.

Comment: If the 3rd party product does not actually copy the template file, then the script will naturally not be included.

Comment: Txs tehhowch, that makes sense. I guess my only option then is to have  a standalone script. What would you suggest is the best way to execute the script when the generated report is opened - web app or trigger.